# JavaScript variables, scope, and garbage collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, garbage-collection

I have some CoffeeScript code in which I initialize a few classes on `document.ready`. I need these classes to exist for as long as the user is on this page. I have an MVC architecture built around the EaselJS canvas API. So far they have all worked fine, but I am worried that the garbage collector might pick them up under some strange circumstance. My code is:

```
$ ->
  seating_chart_view = new SeatingChartView canvas_id: 'seating_chart'
  sections_view = new SectionsView()
  seat_view = new SeatView()
  seating_chart_controller = new SeatingChartController()
```

I'm using the observer pattern to keep track of events, so when something happens a certain class or DOM element might fire some sort of `$(document).trigger(blah_blah_blah)` and another class will be listening for `blah_blah_blah`.

Comment: Anything that's in a global variable will never be garbage collected as long as the page is open, since it can be accessed through the `window` object.

Comment: And if you have an observer object that has references to them, they won't be GCed as long as the observer is around.

Comment: The basic rule of automatic garbage collection is: if there's any way to get to the object, then it won't be removed from memory.